# xml for localisation in Laravel 4

Tags: php, localization, laravel, laravel-4

I'm working a website with Laravel 4 with 3 languages supported (en, fr, es) ,

I need to make the localization file easily editable by users who don't have PHP skills but know XML.

My XML file looks like this :

```
<data>
    <menu>
        <home>Home</home>
        <contact>Contact</contact>
    </menu>
</data>
```

I would like to automatically parse this XML file and use it as source for localization. As it is my first project with Laravel, any suggestions? I know how to parse the XML but don't know how to tell Laravel to use this as localization source.

Comment: If you look at how Laravel sets up the translation in [the service provider](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Translation/TranslationServiceProvider.php), you'll see the translator and its 'config loader' are two separate things. This is a good thing. It means that you should only need to change the loader. You should be able to use `$app->bindShared('translation.loader')` to bind over the top of Laravel's own loader, but you need to ensure you do it before the first resolution of the translator, as the translator's set-up gets the loader our of the container.

Comment: And obviously the loader you specify must implement `Illuminate\Translation\LoaderInterface`

Comment: Thanks, I will check that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a loader that implement Illuminate\Translation\LoaderInterface,which load your xml as translation source
2. Open app.php,and change Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider  to your own loader

3.You should be able to check it by calling trans("yourXmlFile.yourTerms");